# When does System.gc() do something?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I know that garbage collection is automated in Java. But I understood that if you call `System.gc()` in your code that the JVM may or may not decide to perform garbage collection at that point. How does this work precisely? On what basis/parameters exactly does the JVM decide to do (or not do) a GC when it sees `System.gc()`?

Are there any examples in which case it's a good idea to put this in your code?

Comment: Too complex of a concept to full detail here, but this article should help you: http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/

Comment: The exact behaviour is up to the JVM, i.e. implementation dependent.

Answer (score 62):

In practice, it *usually* decides to do a garbage collection.  The answer varies depending on lots of factors, like which JVM you're running on, which mode it's in, and which garbage collection algorithm it's using.

I wouldn't depend on it in your code.  If the JVM is about to throw an OutOfMemoryError, calling System.gc() won't stop it, because the garbage collector will attempt to free as much as it can before it goes to that extreme.  The only time I've seen it used in practice is in IDEs where it's attached to a button that a user can click, but even there it's not terribly useful.

Comment: you can force a garbage collection in jconsole

Comment: @bene Can you really "force" it?  Is jconsole just calling System.gc()?

Comment: I'd use `System.gc()` while in a loading screen for a video game. At that point, I wouldn't really care if the call cleared everything it possibly could, or did nothing at all. I would, however, *prefer* that it "expend effort toward recycling unused objects" during the loading screen, rather than during the gameplay.

Answer (score 30):

You have no control over GC in java -- the VM decides.  I've never run across a case where `System.gc()` is *needed*.  Since a `System.gc()` call simply SUGGESTS that the VM do a garbage collection and it also does a FULL garbage collection (old and new generations in a multi-generational heap), then it can actually cause **MORE** cpu cycles to be consumed than necessary.

In some cases, it may make sense to suggest to the VM that it do a full collection NOW as you may know the application will be sitting idle for the next few minutes before heavy lifting occurs.  For example, right after the initialization of a lot of temporary object during application startup (i.e., I just cached a TON of info, and I know I won't be getting much activity for a minute or so).  Think of an IDE such as eclipse starting up -- it does a lot to initialize, so perhaps immediately after initialization it makes sense to do a full gc at that point.

Answer (score 30):

The only example I can think of where it makes sense to call System.gc() is when profiling an application to search for possible memory leaks. I believe the profilers call this method just before taking a memory snapshot.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do as well. The values returned by Runtime.freeMemory() e.g. are only really meaningful after a System.gc(), because normally you want to know how much memory is blocked by uncollectable instances. Only to be used in debugging/memory profiling of course, never in production.

Comment: Naw, its good for many other scenarios too. For example, lets say you have a single pattern that is lifecycle aware. In onStop() if you are null(ing) the instance, it's a good idea to call System.gc() to help it.

Answer (score 27):

The Java Language Specification does not guarantee that the JVM will start a GC when you call `System.gc()`. This is the reason of this "may or may not decide to do a GC at that point".

Now, if you look at [OpenJDK source code](http://openjdk.java.net/), which is the backbone of Oracle JVM, you will see that a call to `System.gc()` does start a GC cycle. If you use another JVM, such as J9, you have to check their documentation to find out the answer. For instance, Azul's JVM has a garbage collector that runs continuously, so a call to `System.gc()` won't do anything

Some other answer mention starting a GC in JConsole or VisualVM. Basically, these tools make a remote call to `System.gc()`.

Usually, you don't want to start a garbage collection cycle from your code, as it messes up with the semantics of your application. Your application does some business stuff, the JVM takes care of memory management. You should keep those concerns separated (don't make your application do some memory management, focus on business).

However, there are few cases where a call to `System.gc()` might be understandable. Consider, for example, microbenchmarks. No-one wants to have a GC cycle to happen in the middle of a microbenchmark. So you may trigger a GC cycle between each measurement to make sure every measurement starts with an empty heap.

Answer (score 17):

You need to be very careful if you call `System.gc()`. Calling it can add unnecessary performance issues to your application, and it is not guaranteed to actually perform a collection. It is actually possible to disable explicit `System.gc()` via the java argument `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`.

I'd highly recommend reading through the documents available at [Java HotSpot Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/index.jsp) for more in depth details about garbage collection.

Comment: My android application always throws me an OutOfMemoryException. So I was thinking of using System.gc() in the onDestroy function of my class to clear all the unwanted references and objects . Is it a good approach

Comment: @Sagar Devanga  Manually calling the gc as you describe is unlikely to help.  Before throwing an OOM, the JVM will already have attempted to garbage collect in order to free up memory

Answer (score 12):

`System.gc()` is implemented by the VM, and what it does is implementation specific. The implementer could simply return and do nothing, for instance.

As for when to issue a manual collect, the only time when you may want to do this is when you abandon a large collection containing loads of smaller collections--a 
`Map<String,<LinkedList>>`   for instance--and you want to try and take the perf hit then and there, but for the most part, you shouldn't worry about it. The GC knows better than you--sadly--most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

If you use direct memory buffers, the JVM doesn't run the GC for you even if you are running low on direct memory.

If you call `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` and you get an OutOfMemoryError you can find this call is fine after triggering a GC manually.

Comment: Are you saying that System.gc() collects direct allocations whereas the JVM normally does not (before throwing a OOM). Because I think that is wrong. The only reason an allocation might suceed after a explicite GC is the additional time and some more likellyhood of a in-heap object with a finalizer beeing freed (and freeing some directly allocated object).

Comment: In the latest version of Java 6, the code in allocateBuffer will always run a System.gc() before throwing an OutOfMemoryError.  In the finalization code it has a short cut for `Cleaners` of which direct memory uses. i.e. it is not freed by the finaliser thread as this can be too slow.  Even so, it is possible to get an OOME if you are creating direct memory regions particularly fast.  The solution is to not do that and re-use your direct memory regions where you can.

Comment: thanks, this sounds more like my experience. So I guess the answer is only correct for older Java versions.

Answer (score 5):

Most JVMs will kick off a GC (depending on the -XX:DiableExplicitGC and -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent switch). But the specification is just less well defined in order to allow better implementations later on.

The spec needs clarification: [Bug #6668279: (spec) System.gc() should indicate that we don't recommend use and don't guarantee behaviour](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6668279)

Internally the gc method is used by RMI and NIO, and they require synchronous execution, which: this is currently in discussion:

[Bug #5025281: Allow System.gc() to trigger concurrent (not stop-the-world) full collections](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5025281)

Answer (score 4):

`Garbage Collection` is good in `Java`, if we are executing Software coded in java in Desktop/laptop/server. You can call `System.gc()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` in `Java`.

Just note that none of those calls are guaranteed to do anything. They are just a suggestion for the jvm to run the Garbage Collector. It's up the the JVM whether it runs the GC or not. So, short answer: we don't know when it runs. Longer answer: JVM would run gc if it has time for that.

I believe, the same applies for Android. However, this might slow down your system.

Comment: _JVM would run gc if it has time for that_ : not always true, Jvm can run gc when the Eden memory is full.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the VM would do a garbage collection automatically before throwing an OutOfMemoryException, so adding an explicit call shouldn't help except in that it perhaps moves the performance hit to an earlier moment in time.

However, I think I encountered a case where it might be relevant. I'm not sure though, as I have yet to test whether it has any effect:

When you memory-map a file, I believe the map() call throws an IOException when a large enough block of memory is not available. A garbage collection just before the map() file might help prevent that, I think. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

we can never force garbage collection. System.gc is only suggesting vm for garbage collection, however, really what time the mechanism runs, nobody knows, this is as stated by JSR specifications.

Answer (score 2):

There is a LOT to be said in taking the time to test out the various garbage collection settings, but as was mentioned above it usually not useful to do so.

I am currently working on a project involving a memory-limited environment and a relatively large amounts of data--there are a few large pieces of data that push my environment to its limit, and even though I was able to bring memory usage down so that in theory it should work just fine, I would still get heap space errors---the verbose GC options showed me that it was trying to garbage collect, but to no avail. In the debugger, I could perform System.gc() and sure enough there would be "plenty" of memory available...not a lot of extra, but enough.

Consequently, The only time my application calls System.gc() is when it is about to enter the segment of code where large buffers necessary for processing the data will be allocated, and a test on the free memory available indicates that I'm not guaranteed to have it.  In particular, I'm looking at a 1gb environment where at least 300mb is occupied by static data, with the bulk of the non-static data being execution-related except when the data being processed happens to be at least 100-200 MB at the source.  It's all part of an automatic data conversion process, so the data all exists for relatively short periods of time in the long run.

Unfortunately, while information about the various options for tuning the garbage collector is available, it seems largely an experimental process and the lower level specifics needed to understand how to handle these specific situations are not easily obtained.

All of that being said, even though I am using System.gc(), I still continued to tune using command line parameters and managed to improve the overall processing time of my application by a relatively significant amount, despite being unable to get over the stumbling block posed by working with the larger blocks of data.   That being said, System.gc() is a tool....a very unreliable tool, and if you are not careful with how you use it, you will wish that it didn't work more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if your `System.gc()` is called, you can with the new Java 7 update 4 get notification when the JVM performs Garbage Collection.

I am not 100% sure that the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html) class was introduces in Java 7 update 4 though, because I couldn't find it in the release notes, but I found the information in the [javaperformancetuning](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/newtips138.shtml).com site

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a specific example when it is good to run explicit GC.

In general, running explicit GC can actually cause more harm than good, because an explicit gc will trigger a full collection, which takes significantly longer as it goes through every object.  If this explicit gc ends up being called repeatedly it could easily lead to a slow application as a lot of time is spent running full GCs.

Alternatively if going over the heap with a heap analyzer and you suspect a library component to be calling explicit GC's you can turn it off adding: gc=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC  to the JVM parameters.

Comment: We call System.gc() to try to close our MappedByteBuffer objects which otherwise are not closed, and therefore not available for other processes or for file truncation, even though we call 'close()' on the objects. Unfortunately it still doesn't always close them.

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel, one use case for explicit **System.gc()** call is when you want to force finalization, i.e. the call to **finalize** method.

Comment: NB: there is an own method to force the finalisation run. (The problem is actually not in running finalizers but recognizing that a object can be finalized because it is unreferenced)

Answer (score 0):

while system.gc works,it will stop the world:all respones are stopped so garbage collector can scan every object to check if it is needed deleted. if the application is a web project, all request are stopped until gc finishes,and this will cause your web project can not work in a monent.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started using System.gc() method while solving DSA problems in leetcode platform.

Without System.gc() my code was taking about 44mb(Lets say) and
using with System.gc() my code was taking about 41.5mb.

There was gap of 2.5 mb, just by including System.gc() statement in my code.

But it has a trade off too,
Earlier my runtime was around 1ms,
But after using System.gc() is hikes up to 1.25ms.