# Get statistics of a java application running on local machine

Tags: java, statistics, jconsole

I have a java application running on my local machine. I want to get the memory and CPU usage of that java application periodically using a java class. I can see the statistics of the application using JCONSOLE. But I want to get numerical values periodically using a java class. The solution should be applicable to both linux and windows platforms.
How can I do this?

Comment: @ug_ No its not. Because I want to get the memory and cpu usage for one application only.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some useful methods under [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for example,

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Available Processors: " + rt.availableProcessors());
System.out.println("Free Memory: " + rt.freeMemory());
System.out.println("Total Memory: " + rt.totalMemory());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me how can I get those information for only one application. I can get the process ID of that application.

Comment: How many applications are you running per JVM? Assuming it's one the above answer should would for you.

Comment: Jconsole shows me there are 6 java applications running in my machine.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), and look at this [figure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html#gdhqe) especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) can be used "to monitor a local application and view real-time, high-level data on the memory heap, thread activity, and the classes loaded in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Monitoring an application imposes low overhead and can be used for extended periods."

See also [How to monitor Java memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058991/how-to-monitor-java-memory-usage)
for other possibilities.