# Command to list the resources allocated for java process in Ubuntu : 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

I need command to see the list of resources allocated to the java process with PID 3010 as I need to view the actual resources those that are allocated for that process.

On execute the 'top' command, it shows the following.

[image]

the PID 3010 has 1.137g resources. I need to see the list of resources that its allocated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor Java memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058991/how-to-monitor-java-memory-usage)

Comment: I need command to execute which should list the resources allocated for particular PID.

Comment: What makes you think that this is too much?  I'd recommend that you profile the app.

Comment: Edited the question. Please check.

Comment: My advice is the same: Profile it.  You can't tell from the TOP command what's going on.