# Java - Memory Allocation for Classes

Tags: java

Where is the definition of class stored in memory ?

Comment: I suggest that before you ask any more questions, you browse through the JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) and the JVM Spec (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html).

Comment: A class is like a computer science class that you are taking right now. One that you have homework assigned for. One that you will fail if you do not start learning the material instead of asking every question on the interwebs.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263523/does-java-have-automatic-garbage-collection

Comment: In the last hour you have asked 5 questions, all of them are voted -3 at least, do some research before posting your homeworks here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which Java you're talking about

> "the **memory layout of run-time data
>   areas**, the garbage-collection
>   algorithm used, and any internal
>   optimization of the Java virtual
>   machine instructions (for example,
>   translating them into machine code)
>   are left to the discretion of the
>   implementor."

See the [JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html).

That said, Sun Java has a section of memory called the [permanent generation](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation), which includes class definitions.  Because of its original intent (a relatively small area for mostly static classes), the permanent generation doesn't always fit well with dynamic langauges targetting the JVM.  See [this discussion](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2008/02/21/jruby-and-the-permanent-generation) of JRuby issues.  That is part of the motivation for the [Da Vinci Machine project](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/), which aims to improve VM support for such languages.