# Java HashMap Iterator Remove Error

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, hashtable

I have the following Hashmap:

```
Map<String,String> studentGrades = new HashMap<>();
studentGrades.put("Tom", "A+");
studentGrades.put("Jack", "B+");

Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator = studentGrades.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> studentEntry = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(studentEntry.getKey() + " :: " + studentEntry.getValue());
    iterator.remove();
}
```

I thought the `iterator.remove();` meant that something would be removed from the `HashMap`, for example `iterator.remove("Tom");`, then when the iteration happens this is removed from the HashMap.

The program compiles and runs correctly when there `iterator.remove();` but when it is `iterator.remove("Tom");` an error is found. The compiler says

required: no arguments and found: java.lang.String 
reason: actual and formal arguments list differ in length.

Any reason why this is happening or have I got `iterator.remove();` completely wrong?

Comment: You can't pass a String to the remove method because it doesn't work that way. Read up on the Javadocs of Iterator to understand how it works.

Comment: What can be passed to a remove method?

Comment: well the answers are pretty much understandable , and also its a not a good idea to remove an entity from a list  or whatever dataset  you want , while looping in it.

Comment: I was just doing it as a way, to display all of the results (and iterate them) and whilst they are iterating, to remove one and then display the new results in the same loop

Comment: AntJavaDev the `Iterator.remove()` method/API is exactly meant for removing entities while iterating. Filtering data is a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [JavaSE 7 JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()), the *remove* method for *Iterator*:

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation).

It removes the current element from the collection and  "can be called only once per call to next()". It runs against the current value from the iteration and takes no arguments. It's also optional and I'm not certain what all you'd gain by your example. You should be fine without it.

As an aside: I would recommend, as you're iterating a *HashMap* that perhaps you try the for-in approach, as such:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> studentGrades = new HashMap<String, String>();
    studentGrades.put("Tom", "A+");
    studentGrades.put("Jack", "B+");

    for( Map.Entry<String, String> studentEntry : studentGrades.entrySet() ){
        System.out.println(studentEntry.getKey() +" :: "+ studentEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE (per comment thread):
As an aside, I gave this a go and it worked correctly, outputting without error. If you're dead set on using a java.util.Iterator with the Iterator's next *remove* method, this should work. I tested it in [a scrapbook page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-create_scrapbook_page.htm) for convenience.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> studentGrades = new HashMap<String, String>();
    studentGrades.put("Tom", "A+");
    studentGrades.put("Jack", "B+");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iterator = studentGrades.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,String> studentEntry = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(studentEntry.getKey() + " :: " + studentEntry.getValue());
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed help. I have tried that but get an error with studentGrades.entry() ) saying that the method entry is not found

Comment: That's because I had a typo and forgot to put _entrySet()_ instead of _entry()_. It's updated. Basically, you can (more directly?) iterate just the Map Entry pairs instead of creating an iterator. We can do the same with less lines of code. Here's [a decent link on the Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) (as opposed to Collection, Set, etc.).

Comment: Thank you again, the entrySet() has come up with an error saying incompatible types (the brackets)

Comment: Yeah, when I updated my example, I set the type where you define the HashMap; you can remove it if you like.

Comment: I am quite new to Java so I don't really know what that means sorry

Comment: Your HashMap can be generic, or you can enforce its type; so _HashMap<String, String>_ would only allow String keys and String values, for instance. Hang in there, it's a worthwhile language.

Comment: Thank you for your help it has been very useful, it is now working. One last question - why do you recommend the for loop instead of while? and is there a way to remove an entry from the HashMap whilst the iteration is happening (for example if there are 4 entries and remove the second one)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want or need to remove each entry from the HashMap as you go? [Java has automatic garbage collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2263526), so unless you persist the object, it'll eventually take care of itself.

Comment: was just doing it as a way, to display all of the results (and iterate them) and whilst they are iterating, to remove one and then display the new results in the same loop

Comment: Well, I know you _can_ use the remove with an Iterator, I just haven't had need to and was curious as to the use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods named `remove` **in different classes/interfaces**.

1. `Iterator`'s `remove()` removes the previous item returned.
2. `Collection`'s `remove(object)` removes a specific object from a collection

Only the second has a `object` parameter. But beware: using it invalidates iterators, so don't call it from a loop over the same collection, it will not work. For filtering, use an iterator (like you do), and its `remove()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So within my Iterator code, where would I place Iterator remove to remove a specific key?

Comment: [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is not [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (at least not in inheritance way). Collections have `remove(element)` maps have `remove(key)`, so consider changing `Collection` to `Map`.

Comment: within my Iterator code, where would I place Iterator remove to remove a specific key?

Comment: Put an `if` around your `remove()`... and read the documentation of `Iterator`!