# Ensuring OpenGL Texture Memory is Released

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es

My application is running out of memory which switching between two activities.  The first activity is running an OpenGL scene, the second activity is not.  I want to make sure I am releasing all of the textures used by the OpenGL scene.

Right now I am using this method

```
getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()
```

to track the relative amount of memory used by the textures.  This number goes up by about 4 megs if I allocate textures.  However it never seems to go back down again.

In my first activities 'OnPause' I have the following code:

```
SurfaceView.onPause();
mTexture = null;
```

In the second activity I then call getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() several times.  Even after the GC has run and the memory still has not dropped.

Edit:

After more research it appears it is something with the code that loads the data.  I have removed OpenGL from the equation and the memory is still not being released.

```
try {
        InputStream is = null;
        {
            AssetManager am = MyActivity.getAssetMgr();
            is = am.open( fileName );
        }

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );
        if( b != null ) {
            mResX = b.getWidth();
            mResY = b.getHeight();
            Bitmap.Config bc = b.getConfig();
            if( bc == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 )
                mBPP = 4;
            else
                mBPP = 2;

            mImageData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( mResX * mResY * mBPP );
            mImageData.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
            b.copyPixelsToBuffer( mImageData );
            mImageData.position( 0 );


            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Edit2:

I did end up adding in all your ideas.  However this seemed to be the problem in my case...

[ByteBuffer not releasing memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060307/bytebuffer-not-releasing-memory/5305589#5305589)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you mean textures loaded to GPU via gl.glTexImage* or any other helper method. In that case GC wont help you, it is not cleaning internal memory used by textures

Have you tried manually deleting your textures via gl.glDeleteTextures?

**Edit according to new code:**

Several leaks in your code:

- close the input stream
- recycle your bitmap after you have copied data to ByteBuffer
- I guess you use the byteBuffer with image data to upload texture to GPU, make sure you do not store references to those buffers after data was uploaded.

I do not see any other problems in the this code, if after this fixes it still wont work, than look close at any bitmap usages in your app.

Comment: I am just referring to the data being passed to OpenGL.  Since I posted earlier I have removed OpenGL from the equation so it must be something with my ByteBuffer or Bitmap handling.  On a side note, when using a Surface view would would you call glDeleteTextures?  There is function to override when onPause is called, right now I am saying the GL10 object in each texture but it seems a little hacky.

Comment: Regarding glDeleteTextures - in general you should not delete them, android will do it for you. I am just not sure if it will be on app close or activity pause. But anyway memory used in GPU should not affect your second screen

Comment: -close the input stream - Check
-recycle your bitmap after you have copied data to ByteBuffer - Check
-I guess you use the byteBuffer with image data to upload texture to GPU, make sure you do not store references to those buffers after data was uploaded. - So after I pass the byte buffer in via glTexImage2D, it is fine to release the ByteBuffer? I'll give that a shot.