# DeleteGlobalRef crash on ICS

Tags: android, crash, android-ndk

I use NDK to allocate large buffer for Java:

```
allocNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject cls, jlong size) {
    void* buffer = malloc(size);
    jobject directBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, size);
    jobject globalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(directBuffer);
    return globalRef;
}
```

After using this buffer I deallocate it:

```
freeNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject cls, jobject globalRef) {
    void *buffer = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(globalRef);
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(globalRef);
    free(buffer);
}
```

On Android 2.2 it works fine, but on Android 4.0.3 application crashes during DeleteGlobalRef call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of global and local references was completely overhauled in ICS, with intention to improve memory management on the Java side. Find the explanation in [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html) Read more in the [developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html).

In the nutshell, whatever you receive in a JNI function, including the `globalRef` parameter of `freeNativeBuffer()` function, are **local references**. You can create and keep a global reference in your C code, like this:

```
static jobject globalRef;

allocNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject cls, jlong size) {
    void* buffer = malloc(size);
    jobject directBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buffer, size);
    globalRef = env->NewGlobalRef(directBuffer);
    return directBuffer;
}

freeNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* env, jobject cls, jobject localRef) {
    void *buffer = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(localRef);
    if (buffer == env->GetDirectBufferAddress(globalRef) {
        /* we received the object that we saved */
        env->DeleteGlobalRef(globalRef);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

**PS** I found the [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060307/bytebuffer-not-releasing-memory) which looks like the inspiration for your experiment. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060307/bytebuffer-not-releasing-memory#9891217) which explains that there was no need to create and delete global references in the first place.