# When does JNI decide that it can release memory?

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

When I return a direct ByteBuffer to JNI, how long until it can get reclaimed by the JVM/GC?

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
void* func()
{
  [ ... ]
  jobject result = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(testClass, doSomethingMethod);
  void* pointerToMemory = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(result);
  return pointerToMemory;

}
```

The JVM can't possibly know how long I'm going to use that `pointerToMemory`, right? What if I want to hold on to that address and the corresponding memory for a while?

Suppose I want to circumvent this issue and return a byte[] from Java to JNI like this:

```
ByteBuffer buf;
byte[] b = new byte[1000];
buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); 

return buf.array();
```

AND THEN do the same as above, I store a pointer to that byte[] and want to hold on to it for a while. How / when / why is the JVM going to come after that backing byte[] from Java?

```
void* function()
{
  jbyteArray byteArr = (jbytearray)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(testClass, doSomethingMethod);
  jbyte *b= env->GetByteArrayElements(byteArr, 0);  
  return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: If the function implements a native method, the pointer will be invalid as soon as you return.

To avoid this, you should get a global reference for all objects that you intend to keep valid after returning. See the documentation on [local and global references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242) for more information.

To understand better how JNI manages references from native code, see the [documentation on PushLocalFrame/PopLocalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#push_local_frame).

Comment: Suppose the second szenario I posted: I return a byte[] from Java. It will get copied, right? How do I know when things get copied? Is there documentation somewhere that tells me that the byte[] will be copied? I just assume it does, because there is a ReleaseByteElements() function. But here is the most important thing: Can I use free() instead of the ReleaseByteElements() call?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you look into the documentation, the third parameter (`isCopy`) to `GetByteArrayAlElements` tells you if it has been copied. But you shouldn't assume that you can use `free()`. It might work with some version of the JVM, but break in the future or in other JVMs. Stick to the API.

Comment: jop, do you know that if I do NewDirectByteBuffer(b) where b is malloc'ed memory in C, is the JVM going to try and touch and delete it? If not, I think the safest option for me, is to make a JNI call like in this link, that way I have full control over my memory and can free it in C whenever I want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060307/bytebuffer-not-releasing-memory The only remaining worry for me, is that I'm going to run into this JVM bug, because I do need many of these buffers. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4857305 Is there maybe a way to do all this with byte[]

Comment: I think the best solution may be to simply copy everything out manually from the direct buffer address that I get from the buffer that I created in Java. That way the Java GC leaves me alone, and I can free the memory however I please. So I just hope that this DirectBuffer bug got fixed in 1.6 or 1.7. Would piss me off a lot if not :/