# alloc native buffer and use in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have bitmap which I should manipulate both in c++ and Java sides.
Therefore, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060307/bytebuffer-not-releasing-memory) post I allocated the buffer in C++ and passed the reference to Java. In Java I filled the buffer from bitmap using [copyPixelsToBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) method. When I tried to create bitmap from that buffer(without any manipulations) the [decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) returned null. And I don't understand what was my mistak. Below the code which I used.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    mCurrentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(hardCodedPath, options);

    // 4- bytes count per pixel
    bytesCount = mCurrentBitmap.getWidth() * mCurrentBitmap.getHeight() * 4;

    pixels = (ByteBuffer) allocNativeBuffer(bytesCount);
    pixels.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    mCurrentBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(pixels);
    pixels.flip();
    pixels.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    byte[] bitmapdata = new byte[pixels.remaining()];

    pixels.get(bitmapdata);

    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inDither = true;
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length, opt);
```

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it.

`ByteBuffer mPixels = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(  saveWidth*saveHeight*4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
     GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mPixels);`

```
resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
 resultBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mPixels);
```