# Java - memory usage & multiple instances of jar

Tags: java, jar, mongodb

I am currently working with Java, MongoDB and several threads.

For each threads, I run MongoDB connection.

```
private Mongo m;
m = new Mongo();
```

I had a look to the memory usage with TOP and I saw multiple instances of `MongoDB Jar` (call to library mongo-2.6.3.jar). I tried to destroy it after end of processing of each thread with :

```
m.close();
m = null;
System.gc();
```

But nothing instances are still in memory until my program is stopped.

Any ideas ?  Thanks.

---

OK I have made some tests regarding the tutorial, but not very successful.
In fact, I have :

```
public class process {
    public static Mongo m;
    public static DB db;

    public process() {
        m = new Mongo();
        //for each database
        threadDatabase thread = new threadDatabase(database);
        thread.start();
    }
}

public class threadDatabase extends Thread {
    public threadDatabase (String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void run() {
        process.db.requestStart();
        processDatabase(this.database);    
        process.db.requestDone(); 
    }


private boolean processDatabase(String dbname) {
        process.db = process.m.getDB(dbname);
        //getting data on the dedicated database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorial about MongoDB](http://Note:%20The%20Mongo%20object%20instance%20actually%20represents%20a%20pool%20of%20connections%20to%20the%20database;%20you%20will%20only%20need%20one%20object%20of%20class%20Mongo%20even%20with%20multiple%20threads.%20%20See%20the%20concurrency%20doc%20page%20for%20more%20information.)

> The Mongo object instance
>   actually represents a pool of
>   connections to the database; you will
>   only need one object of class Mongo
>   even with multiple threads.  See the
>   [concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency) doc page for more
>   information.

Nulling references and calling `System.gc` does not guarantee to free up or garbage collect any resources at all. Fur further information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/system-gc-in-java).

My advice: Only use one instance of `Mongo` per VM, the rest will be handled automatically.