# How to empty or clear heap memory dynamically

Tags: android, heap-memory, forceclose

My project is totally bases on images. I am using a gallery and a coverflow in my project and due to less heap size the app is forcefully close.

So every time I load my app I want to clear heap size, so I can reuse it.
I have used `System.gc() & recycle ()` method in gallery and coverflow, but my gallery and coverflow, are inter-related so the object is always referenced, so `System.gc()` and `recycle()` are not having effect and my gallery and coverflow still crashes at a random point of time while using it.

For some reason I can't show my code here and even if, it is very big so I can't manage to show here.

Please help me out & thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You don't have any real control over forcing the GC to run. It runs on it's own, whenever it thinks it's time.

[When does System.gc() do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/system-gc-in-java)

So, the only option that you have is to judiciously use images and bitmaps.

Hint => Use soft references.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html

Comment: how to use it with gallery and coverflow

Comment: You will have to search for a working sample. You will find some on the internet. First, try to understand the concept, and then, it will be more clear how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To control the crash due to this memory issue, you need to do like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

The inSampleSize value reduces the memory consumption.

More information can be had from this thread:

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this will decrease my image quality and i cant compromise with image quality

Answer (score 0):

Increase the heap space.. and turn on auto delete, like in eclipse if you go to preferences and manage the heap space; you can click the trash button there