# Get only part of an Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of Integers in Java, I would like use only a part of it. I know in Python you can do something like this array[index:] and it returns the array from the index. Is something like this possible in Java.

Answer (score 598, accepted):

The length of an array in Java is immutable. So, you need to copy the desired part into a new array.

Use [`copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int)) method from [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) class:

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, startIndex, endIndex);
```

> **startIndex** is the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive.
> **endIndex** is the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive. (This index may lie outside the array)

E.g.:

```
   //index   0   1   2   3   4
int[] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 2);          // returns {10, 20}
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, 4);          // returns {20, 30, 40}
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, arr.length); // returns {30, 40, 50} (length = 5)
```

Comment: there seems to be a size limit? only this works: `Arrays.copyOfRange(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(),1,255)` as instead of 255 I cannot use Integer.MAX_VALUE, in case I dont want to get the real length

Comment: @AquariusPower the size limit is the array size, and it can be bigger than 255. You just cannot provide an `endIndex` bigger than the size of the array passed as the first argument. So, if you want a full copy, create a variable referring to this array and use `Arrays.copyOfRange(var, 0, var.length)` or `Arrays.copyOf(var, var.length)`

Comment: I would have to create a local var for the stacktrace sub-array, but I found that this works!!! `Arrays.copyOfRange(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(),1,Short.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: Be careful about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What will happen if startIndex == endIndex, say Arrays.copyofRange(arr, 0, 0) ?

Comment: If `startIndex == endIndex`, a zero length array will be returned.

Comment: there is another problem. What if I need to split the string array of length say 500K into the subarrays of 250K. These method accepts interegr which max out at 65000.

Comment: Integer in Java is max 2^31-1, not 2^16.

Comment: @elias , just the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

You could wrap your array as a list, and request a sublist of it.

```
MyClass[] array = ...;
List<MyClass> subArray = Arrays.asList(array).subList(index, array.length);
```

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you can use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

It does about the same thing (note there is a copy : you don't change the initial array).

Comment: That said, if you don't want to make an explicit copy, you'll need to use a `List` and a `subList` as outlined in @K-ballo's answer.

Comment: That's right. Java doesn't have the array slicing facilities that more modern languages offer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd put it that way, but...yes, Java doesn't offer array slicing.  (That said, there are some advantages to this approach: reduced possibilities for memory leaks, reduced array overhead by avoiding the extra fields, etc.  You could go either way.)

Comment: Yes, you're right again (and I didn't try to start a flame war ;) ). Slicing makes GC very complex. And when Java did try object based implicit slicing in Strings [it made it more evident that this was dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951812/java-not-garbage-collecting-memory/10951867#10951867).

Answer (score 20):

You can try:

```
System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 0, targetArray, 0, targetArray.length);// copies whole array

// copies elements 1 and 2 from sourceArray to targetArray
System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 1, targetArray, 0, 2);
```

See [javadoc for System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

Comment: I just love how this is exactly how Arrays.copyOf() and Arrays.copyOfRange() are actually implemented (sans bounds checks) and yet it gets no votes whilst the slightly higher overhead utility method wrappers rack up the votes despite System.arraycopy dating back to 1995.

Comment: I guess it just doesn't look "modern" enough for some.

Comment: I like going old school, no shiny bells and whistles just the required machinery. Like memcpy in C

Comment: But using arrays.copyOfRange() increases readability and reduces significantly the possibility of bugs.

Comment: I've never understood this reasoning. Arrays.copyOfRange() wouldn't have been invented if there weren't a justifiable effect on readability and ease-of-use. Saying something is better because it has existed for longer doesn't justify anything. Slightly more performant is a better argument, but with the key word "slightly", the tradeoff is not invalid for those who find it worth it.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Java 1.6 or greater, you can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to copy a portion of the array. From the javadoc:

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array. The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and `original.length`, inclusive. The value at `original[from]` is placed into the initial element of the copy (unless `from == original.length` or `from == to`). Values from subsequent elements in the original array are placed into subsequent elements in the copy. The final index of the range (`to`), which must be greater than or equal to `from`, may be greater than `original.length`, in which case `false` is placed in all elements of the copy whose index is greater than or equal to `original.length - from`. The length of the returned array will be `to - from`.

Here is a [simple example](http://www.codingdiary.com/developers/developers/diary/javaapi/java/util/SampleCode/CopyofRange8ArrayExampleCode.html):

```
/**
 * @Program that Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new 
 * array.
 * CopyofRange8Array.java 
 * Author:-RoseIndia Team
 * Date:-15-May-2008
 */
import java.util.*;
public class CopyofRange8Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //creating a short array
       Object T[]={"Rose","India","Net","Limited","Rohini"};
        // //Copies the specified  short array upto specified range,
        Object T1[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(T, 1,5);
        for (int i = 0; i < T1.length; i++) 
            //Displaying the Copied short array upto specified range
            System.out.println(T1[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28boolean[],%20int,%20int%29); and example:

```
int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] range(int[] array, int start, int end){
        int returner[] = new int[end-start];
        for(int x = 0; x <= end-start-1; x++){
            returner[x] = array[x+start];
        }
        return returner;
    }
```

this is a way to do the same thing as Array.copyOfRange but without importing anything

Comment: `returner[x] = array[x+start];` does not copy the array.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method on your integers arr, something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(3);
        arr.add(4);
        List<Integer> partialArr = arr.subList(1, 3);

        // print the subArr
        for (Integer i: partialArr)
            System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Output will be: `2 3`.

Note that `subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method performs minus 1 on the 2nd variable it receives (var2 - 1), i don't know exactly why, but that's what happens, maybe to reduce the chance of exceeding the size of the array.