# get a view of the portion of Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I refer to [get only part of an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001720/get-only-part-of-an-array-in-java), it use **copyOfRange()** method. So, i glanced at source code of this method. It copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array. I don't want to do this. I want to get a view of array.

Is there some ways to get this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001772/6732794) answer from the same question that you referenced. Wrap the array with [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) and use [List.subList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
Integer[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

List<Integer> view = Arrays.asList(a).subList(3, 6);

for (int i = 0; i < view.size(); i++)
    view.set(i, view.get(i) * 10);

System.out.println(view);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

prints:

```
[30, 40, 50]
[0, 1, 2, 30, 40, 50, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, you won't be able to wrap arrays of primitive types without boxing the whole array first.

Comment: Good catch. That answer deserves a few more votes. I didn't notice it either.