# How to print out array index 2-5

Tags: java

I was creating a program that had an array involved and at one point I wanted to print out part of the array. I wanted to know how to print out for example array indexes 2-5.

I tried doing something like this but it didn't work.

```
String[] testArray = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f'", "g"};
System.out.println(testArray[2,5]);
```

but it didn't work. (not that I fully expected it too).

I was just wondering how you would do something like this.

Comment: Further to YCF_L's great answer, if you just wanted to pass a slice of the array around, see this answer which shows you how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001772/2357085

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays::copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(boolean%5B%5D,int,int)), like this :

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(testArray, 2, 5)
```

To print the result, you can use :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(testArray, 2, 5)));
```

**Outputs**

```
[c, d, e]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println(testArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **print array element from index 2 to index 5**:

```
public void printArrayInIndexRange(String[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
      for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex && i < array.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(array[i]);
      }       
}
```

Then simply call the method:

```
printArrayInIndexRange(testArray, 2, 5);
```

Note: the condition `i < array.length` helps to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) Using [Arrays.copyOfRange()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) method.

2) If you're using Java8, then you can use streams to do your job as follows:

```
int[] slice = IntStream.range(2, 5)
                        .map(i -> testArray[i])
                        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `System.arraycopy` here is [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

```
// copies elements 2 and 5 from sourceArray to targetArray

    System.arraycopy(sourceArray, 2, targetArray, 0, 4);
```

**OR**

Wrap your `array` as a `list`, and request a `sublist` of it.

```
MyClass[] array = ...;
List<MyClass> subArray = Arrays.asList(array).subList(startIndex, endIndex);
```