# Java - splice string[]

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java, and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to splice a `String[]`. I'm using **Java 11**. As an example, I'm wanting to splice the args in main:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // splice args
}
```

I know in Python this would just be `args[2:]`, but I'm not sure about the equivalent here. I saw for other types you can do use the `.copyOf()`, but I saw in the Oracle docs there isn't a method for Strings.

Comment: Strings are Objects, so `Arrays.copyOfRange` should work.

Comment: You could just use a for-loop. ``String splice = args[2]; for (int i = 3; i < args.length(); i++) { splice += args[i]; }`` Do this only after making sure that args[] has a length of at least 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only part of an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001720/get-only-part-of-an-array-in-java)

Comment: What do you mean with splice? Please provide input and desired output, as most of the answers and comments here seem to think you mean slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java does not have a `splice`, but it does have an `Arrays::copyOfRange`, which takes the array, the `start` and the `end`. So in your case:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 2, args.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a method `static String.join(delimiter,string...)` since Java 1.8.

```
    String[] a = {"one", "two", "three"};
    String b = String.join("", a);
    System.out.println(b);
```

Output

```
onetwothree
```