# opposite of << in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a huge string being prepared by using `<<` operator in a loop. At the end I want to delete the last 2 chars.

```
some_loop
  str << something
end
str = str[0..-3]
```

I think the last operation above would consume memory and time as well, but I'm not sure. I just wanted to see if there is an operation with the opposite effect of  `<<` so I can delete those 2 last chars from the same string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, string slicing is already a fast and memory efficient operation as the string content isn't copied until it's really necessary.

See the detailed explanation at "[Seeing double: how Ruby shares string values](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/18/seeing-double-how-ruby-shares-string-values)".

Note that this is a somewhat classical optimization for string operations; [You have it in java too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951812/java-not-garbage-collecting-memory/10951867#10951867) and we often used similar tricks in C.

So, don't hesitate to do:

```
str = str[0..-3]
```

That's the correct, recommended and efficient way, provided you really have to remove those chars, see Sergio's answer.

Comment: +1 for the link pasted above -> http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/18/seeing-double-how-ruby-shares-string-values

Answer (score 3):

Are you, by any chance, joining some array elements with a separator? Something like this?

```
names = ['Mary', 'John', 'Dave']

res = ''
names.each do |n|
  res << n << ', '
end

res # => 'Mary, John, Dave, '
```

If yes, then there's easier path.

```
names.join(', ') # => 'Mary, John, Dave'
```

Comment: yes, joining some array elements with `, `. But, I know I should be doing some bench-marking on my own, but still want to hear quick comments about how bad it might be to call join when the data strings are too many and huge

Comment: Then this answer is for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If the last two characters are linefeed/newline (CR/LF) you may use `String.chomp` (or `String#chomp!` if you want to modify the string).

Else you may use:

```
2.times{ string.chop! }
```

or

```
string.chop!
string.chop!
```

Comment: Why do tell about `chomp` in the text and give examples using `chop`?

Comment: `chomp` is  for CR/LF. The example with `chop` is in the 'else'-section (it removes the last character).