# Modify non immutable object, java

Tags: java, substring, stringbuilder

I am confused with this example :

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("abcde");
String subStr = a.substring( a.indexOf("a") , a.indexOf("c")  );
int leng = a.length();
char ch = a.charAt(4);
System.out.println( subStr + " " + leng + " " + ch);
//the result will be : subStr = abc  , leng = 5  ch = e
```

My question is : Why **ch = e** and it doesn't create an Exception ?

My thinking:
I have one StringBuilder, a non immutable object and if I use a method on the object it will return me a new value of the object with the same reference object.

- Why when I am using `a.substring ( int a, int b )`, it is not modifying the object StringBuilder ?
- Why if I use the method `a.append("value")` I am modifying the value of the StringBuilder object?

Comment: Your question is confusing -- please try to clarify.

Comment: Calling `subString(...)` is a non-mutating method call. It simply returns a segment of the String or StringBuilder. Please edit your question itself for clarity. Specify exactly what in the API confuses you.

Comment: [Returns a **new** String that contains a subsequence of characters currently contained in this sequence. The substring begins at the specified start and extends to the character at index end - 1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring(int,%20int))

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just to clarify. Since Java 7, no-more the segment of the string is returned. Earlier it was the case causing memory leak and was a bug which was fixed. Please find more details [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-substring-in-java-works.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612157/substring-method-in-string-class-causes-memory-leak)

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar: many thanks for this information. I had not previously known about this interesting aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one StringBuilder, a non immutable object and if I use a method on the object it will return me a new value of the object with the same reference object.

- Not always will a method return you the same reference object. It might create a new object and return that. Its always better to check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) before you assume anything.

> Why when I am using `a.substring ( int a, int b )`, it is not modifying the object `StringBuilder`?

- If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring%28int,%20int%29), it clearly states that `substring(int,int)` method *Returns a **new String***. That answers why your object is not being modified.

> Why if I use the method `a.append("value")` I am modifying the value of the `StringBuilder` object?

- Again if you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) for `append(String)`, it clearly states that it - *Returns: a reference to **this object.***. This method complies with what *"your thinking"* was.

Answer (score 5):

The [.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring(int,%20int)) method is returning a **new** `String` object, it does not modify the `StringBuilder` itself.

Comment: I think that's it.  The line is `char c = a.charAt(4);`  That's the original "abcde" StringBuilder, not `subStr`.

Comment: I think the OP was confused about why the `.substring()` method is not modifying the `StringBuilder` contents, as he was expecting a different output for the `ch` character.

Answer (score 0):

> Why when i am using a.substring ( int a, int b ) it is not modifying
>   the object StringBuilder ?

because `substring()` returns a new string ,it doesn't modify `StringBuilder`.

`char ch = a.charAt(4);` , `charAt()` returns a char based on the index and since index is  zero base ,it returns `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because an object is 'mutable' does not mean every method that object can perform has to modify it. Common examples are equals(), getClass() ... append() however **does** modify the StringBuilder object.