# Deconstructor in Java?

Tags: java, destructor

My java application can't work without static variables and I've declared a good amount of static variables in my application. But, there's a problem: Is there any deconstructor in java that i can use to free up the memory used by by these static variables?
There's a `Statement` variable, for which i can use `close()` to free up some memory.
I want to know, what really happens when `stmt.close()` method is called?
PS: Is this possible, by providing a null value to the object (`myStaticObject=null`) and calling `System.gc()` will do the job?

Comment: make your application work without good amount of static variables.

Comment: There is no deconstructor. Just make your variable available to Garbage collector.

Comment: Java handles garabage collection for you, you have to make them available for collection.

Comment: there is no destructor concept in java. here memory management is automatic and JVM is doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear AnkitNeo you have given the answer yourself.

By setting the variable to null and calling

```
System.gc();
```

you will free up the memory. However, it is not guaranteed that System.gc() will actually garbage collect. According to this post: [When does System.gc() do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/when-does-system-gc-do-anything) most of the time the system will garbage collect. I believe it will just not GC if there is currently a very high CPU load.

Comment: Ha!I was just confirming. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AnkitNeo it's almost certainly a bad idea to call the garbage collector manually. Really, don't do it unless you have a very clear reason to do so. Just setting to null is enough to allow the system to reclaim the memory when it needs it.

Comment: I would strengthen the case made by @chiastic-security Don't do this even if you think you have a very clear reason to do so. 100% of the calls to System.gc() that I have seen in application code were bugs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to free the memory of a static field `x`, then yes, just set

```
x = null;
```

Except in very rare cases, you shouldn't need to worry about calling the garbage collector yourself: the system will do that for you, and usually knows better than you when it's appropriate to do so.

All that said, a program with lots of static fields is usually a warning sign that the design isn't quite right. Good design usually (not always) associates fields with instances. You should at least ask yourself whether you should restructure your code.

Answer (score 1):

The Java language does not have a deconstructor feature, since it has its own garbage collection, which relieves the programmer from manually freeing memory for no longer referenced variables.

`stmt.close` will close all database resources used by the `Statement` object. It does not tell the garbage collector that the reference is no longer used.

Yes you can invoke a one-time `System.gc()` after closing all resources (although this does not guarantee an immediate action by the GC thread), and after assigning `null` to the reference. However, assigning the `null` alone would normally be enough to tell the GC thread that the variable is no longer referenced without the need to explicitly run the GC.

Comment: Java has the `finalize()` method, which is a bit like a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `finalize()` method you can override. It will be executed if the object is collected by the JVM. However, there no guaranteed way to control the collection of the project. Call `System.gc()` works most of the time, depending on what the JVM thinks.

In a nutshell, what you said will work most of the time.

Hope this helps you.