# In Java Memory allocated to string buffer is not getting cleared

Tags: java, jvm

Memory allocated to string buffer is not getting cleared even we did

```
stringbuffer.delete(0,Stringbuffer.length());
stringbuffer = null;
System.gc();
```

Any suggestion to remove entire memory allocated to string buffer.

Comment: When gc runs it will clear memory is there are no references to it.  How do you know that the memory is not being cleared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does System.gc() do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/when-does-system-gc-do-anything)

Comment: Remove from what? Is it supposed to punch a hole into your RAM chips? The garbage collector will make the RAM *available* to other objects, not modify it. As long as no-one reuses the memory for other purposes, it may keep its old contents. That also applies to other programming languages with manual memory deallocation.

Comment: StringBuilder.delete() doesn't free any memory. Not using the stringBuilder anywhere makes it available for clean up.  BTW Please don't use StringBuffer if you can as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: _"Memory allocated to string buffer is not getting cleared"_ How do you know?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control Java memory management. Even by calling `System.gc()`.  By calling `System.gc()` you can only suggest JVM to collect garbage but cannot force to free memory
Java will collect garbage memory based on its algorithm only

`System.gc()` javadoc says

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend
>   effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory
>   they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns
>   from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort
>   to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Source :-[System.gc()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc())