# Any Situation requires to manually call System.gc() in java?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

Under what specific circumstances, calling System.gc() have a great positive effect, and not considered as a useless action?

That may imply, if:

- Calling System.gc() solves a frequent bug or crash, and have a clear connection in between
- Calling System.gc() saves development time
- Have significant positive effect on performance or resource saving
- other related worth to mention

Excluded:

- What could possibly go wrong
- saves 2KB memory

I've searched with some keywords but haven't find any existing questions. Glad to know if there is any.

Found lots of posts about how to call gc, and does gc actually do. But none of them related to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does System.gc() do something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540/when-does-system-gc-do-something)

Comment: External article that seems to consider this exact topic: https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-gc